# google sheet replace regex formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to remove any string that matches: `_digitsxdigits` like `_8x7` and `_999x1`

```
=ArrayFormula(if((Input!A10:A=TRUE), SUBSTITUTE(Input!E10:E, REGEXEXTRACT(Input!E10:E,"[0-9]x[0-9]"),""), ""))
```

I get this error, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Try `=ArrayFormula(if((A10:A=TRUE), REGEXREPLACE(E10:E,"-[0-9]+x[0-9]+",""), ""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A10:A=TRUE, REGEXREPLACE(E10:E, "(_\d+x\d+)", ), ))
```

Comment: I get a REF error: `Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings.`
BTW what does it mean when you put no argument as 2nd argument?

Comment: @EladBenda can you share a copy of your sheet? (it means the 2nd argument will output no value)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(if((A10:A=TRUE), REGEXREPLACE(E10:E,"([0-9])+x([0-9])+",""), ""))
```